# Electromagnetic door locks in series or parallel

Tags: electromagnetic

I am planning to add two 12V electromagnetic door locks to a door. Should they be connected in series or parallel to the power supply? Or is it advised for each to have its own power supply?
The Power supply is a 24V power supply.

Comment: Most likely parallel. Read the datasheet or manual.

Comment: You forgot to state the voltage of the power supply. Hit the edit link below your question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a 12V power supply, then connect them in parallel, or use two power supplies if that's easier.

If it's a 24V DC power supply, and the locks are identical, then connect them in series.

If they are AC locks, or not identical, then connect each to their own supply.